# How to use moltin cart package for laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Am new to laravel 4 and am having issues instaling the Moltin Cart package

i've required on my composer.json file added the vendor and repo in app.php but still get this error.

> Argument 1 passed to Moltin\Cart\Cart::__construct() must be an
>   instance of Moltin\Cart\StorageInterface, instance of
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Application given, called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\r6images\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository.php
>   on line 123 and defined

Comment: Describe what steps you did to install it

Comment: The one i was using wasn't for laravel 4 but i found a laravel 4 package here: moltin / laravel-cart - https://github.com/moltin

Answer (score 0):

Found a laravel 4 package here:
moltin / laravel-cart - https://github.com/moltin